# Javascript access functions of constructor

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `twillioObject`.

When I do a console.log of `twillioObject`, I get this output in developer tools:

[image: Screenshot of developer tools log]

I want an object of the Connection and Device classes. It seems that I can't reach it.

I have experience in JavaScript but I haven't seen this situation before. How does this work?

Comment: doing `twilloObject.constructor.Connection` should work. Note that they are not classes, they are constructors. In js there is no real classes, only constructors. Even when you use the `class` keyword you're not creating a class. The `class` keyword generates a constructor.

Comment: Okay, I tried that but was giving an error, but the error was not related to this so this is the right solution. If u make an answer of it, I will mark it as the right one. Thanks!